# HTML5 web stack options

Tags: php, html, lamp

I am new to non-Microsoft world of web apps. I am quite familiar with the MS web app stack typically comprising the following:

Database - SQL Server or Oracle
Server side programming - ASP.NET, C#/VB.NET, WCF
Client side programming - Silverlight, AJAX, Javascript

The app i am trying to develop is a simple web app with rich UI harnessing the potentials of HTML5 and providing some kind of thin client capability in the browser.

I am trying to come up with the options for a complete non-microsoft stack for web apps. Initial ideas are to use HTML5 for client-side presentation layer and PHP for server side programming. There are few frameworks for HTML5 that i found online. I guess, the HTML5 adoption is going to be in the form of frameworks. But, i am still getting started.

What technologies have you used in combination for the stack to work well? I have separated them to layers, so i can understand the options for each layer better and also the stack that you think works better. Thanks much!

Database - ?
Server side programming - ?
Web servers - ?
Client side programming - ?
Presentation layer - ?

I am looking to experiment with various stack options that you might have used in the past.

Comment: There's no specific server-side requirement to use HTML 5 features on the client. I'd be much more worried about what technologies you're comfortable with yourself on the server. HTML 5 has not that much do to with that decision.

Comment: As for recommendations: Server side programming: whatever tickles your fancy and matches your targeted hosting environment. Database: whatever works well with your programming language of choice and your targeted hosting environment. Web server: whatever your programming language of choice can run on well, Apache being a good standard. Client side programming: Is there any other choice but Javascript? Presentation layer: Any choice but HTML/CSS?

Comment: @deceze: I totally understand that HTML5 is a client side presentation technology that could be used with various server side technologies. And, i am trying to understand the various technologies on various layers that could work with HTML5 on the client side. My apologies, if my question wasn't so clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many good solutions, though I'll outline some possibilities here that I'm familiar with:

- Database - MySQL, PostgreSQL
- Server side programming - PHP, Python, Perl, C/CGI
- Web servers - Apache, lighttpd, nginx
- Client side programming - JavaScript
- Presentation layer - HTML, CSS

  - SVG for embedded vectors
  - MathML for equation rendering
  - RSS for feeds

Answer (score 0):

If you want almost zero server config, google app engine might be a good choice for this, although they only have a non-relational database.